# Most efficient way to union two result sets while excluding same results from one set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with current and default values.

```
create table temp_se (
  id varchar2(1),
  default_value varchar2(1),
  sequence number
)
/

insert into temp_se values ('A', 'N', 1);
insert into temp_se values ('B', 'N', 2);
insert into temp_se values ('C', 'N', 3);
insert into temp_se values ('D', 'N', 4);
insert into temp_se values ('E', 'N', null);
insert into temp_se values ('A', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('B', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('C', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('D', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('E', 'Y', 5);
/
```

The task is to return all current values and add missing values from default values based on ID.

I was wondering what's is the most efficient way to do this, my current approach is:

```
with data as
 (select 1 rank, t.*
    from temp_se t
   where default_value = 'N'
     and nvl(sequence, -1) < 3
  union
  select 2 rank, t.*
    from temp_se t
   where default_value = 'Y'),
ranked as
 (select rank() over(partition by id order by rank) rank_no, t.* from data t)
select id, default_value, sequence from ranked where rank_no = 1;
/
```

I've tried some other approaches, included bellow, but some does not produce desired result or I'm not sure if it's better performance wise. Maybe there's better approach to this problem which I do not know about / haven't tried?

Current ant tried solutions:

```
-- Create and populate table, to reproduce problem
create table temp_se (
  id varchar2(1),
  default_value varchar2(1),
  sequence number
)
/

insert into temp_se values ('A', 'N', 1);
insert into temp_se values ('B', 'N', 2);
insert into temp_se values ('C', 'N', 3);
insert into temp_se values ('D', 'N', 4);
insert into temp_se values ('E', 'N', null);
insert into temp_se values ('A', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('B', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('C', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('D', 'Y', null);
insert into temp_se values ('E', 'Y', 5);
/

--Current approach
-- produces expected result
-- not happy with performance
with data as
 (select 1 rank, t.*
    from temp_se t
   where default_value = 'N'
     and nvl(sequence, -1) < 3
  union
  select 2 rank, t.*
    from temp_se t
   where default_value = 'Y'),
ranked as
 (select rank() over(partition by id order by rank) rank_no, t.* from data t)
select id, default_value, sequence from ranked where rank_no = 1;
/

/*
 * What i've tried:
 * */

--union -> default_value flag always differ so everything is included
-- would be nice if you could specify on which columns should be compared
  select *
    from (select *
            from temp_se
           where default_value = 'N'
             and nvl(sequence, -1) < 3
          union
          select *
            from temp_se
           where default_value = 'Y')
   order by id;
--full outer join, using(id) with coalesce, null values are overwritten with default non null values
select id,
       coalesce(current_values.default_value, default_values.default_value) default_value,
       coalesce(current_values.sequence, default_values.sequence) sequence
  from (select *
          from temp_se
         where default_value = 'N'
           and nvl(sequence, -1) < 3) current_values
  full outer join (select * from temp_se where default_value = 'Y') default_values
 using (id);

--exlude default_data values with not in clause
-- produces expected result
-- better cost, IO cost, and bytes read in explain plan compared to current solution
-- however select times are longer
with current_data as
 (select *
    from temp_se
   where default_value = 'N'
     and nvl(sequence, -1) < 3),
default_data as
 (select *
    from temp_se
   where default_value = 'Y'
     and id not in (select id from current_data))
select *
  from current_data
union
select * from default_data;
/

drop table temp_se;
/
```

--EDIT--

Expected result:

| ID | DEFAULT_VALUE | SEQUENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | N | 1 |
| B | N | 2 |
| C | Y |  |
| D | Y |  |
| E | N |  |

Comment: Can you add the specific expected result?

Comment: @TheImpaler added expected result

Comment: Hm, but - could you explain the **rule** that leads to desired result? I don't quite understand ".. return all current values and add missing values from default values based on ID." What does it mean?

Comment: I've tried to simplify as data as much as possible but can see that it's still no very clear. I'll edit my question.

Comment: But... `C` and `D` do have current values `3` and `4`. Why don't they show up in the result?

Comment: Take a look at my current approach, I intentionally filter out those values to produce desired situation. I'll edit my question to clarify use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a union or join; you can rank the rows directly in one pass:

```
select id, default_value, sequence,
  dense_rank() over (partition by id order by default_value, sequence) as rnk
from temp_se
where sequence is null or sequence < 3
```

and then use that as a CTE or line view and filter on `rnk`:

```
select id, default_value, sequence
from (
  select id, default_value, sequence,
    dense_rank() over (partition by id order by default_value, sequence) as rnk
  from temp_se
  where sequence is null or sequence < 3
)
where rnk = 1
```

| ID | DEFAULT_VALUE | SEQUENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | N | 1 |
| B | N | 2 |
| C | Y | *null* |
| D | Y | *null* |
| E | N | *null* |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4937adb5a4efa93fcfe0d65000314774)

Comment: In my attempt to simplify data and question it seems that I failed to accurately describe my use case, tables and data I'm working with. So although this answer provides better solution to the question I asked I do not think it can be applied to my use case. I'll edit my question to hopefully represent my actual case and data I'm working with...

Answer (score 5):

Rephrased your current approach

```
select id, default_value, sequence 
from (
    select t.* , 
       row_number() over(partition by id order by case when default_value = 'N' then 1 else 2 end, nvl(sequence, -1) desc) rn
    from temp_se t
    where default_value = 'N' and (sequence is null or sequence < 3)
       or default_value = 'Y'
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The data is already in one table, this doesn't appear to be a case for union, it appears to be either filtering out results or conditional aggregation.

@Alex.poole and @serg showed filtering, so here's aggregation...

```
WITH
  sample_data AS
(
  -- Apply your filtering
  SELECT t.*
    FROM temp_se t
   WHERE default_value = 'N' AND (sequence is null OR sequence <  3)
      OR default_value = 'Y'
) 
-- Aggregate to one row per id, prioritising default='N'
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(default_value) AS default_value,
  MIN(sequence) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY default_value)  AS sequence
FROM
  sample_data
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY
  id
```

It does seem a convoluted scenario. Is it simply a way of storing the defaults in the same table as you source data? Why not just store the defaults separately and use a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I'm afraid in trying to simplify my question and reduce code needed I failed to accurately describe scenario, use case and data needed. Since the question that I formulated is answered, and there's quite a few answers, I'll accept one of them and post another question, which I hope will accurately describe my use case scenario and data, all that this question failed.